# Stale element reference in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting a stale reference element error on the line below.

```
string url = images[i].GetAttribute("href");
```

Strangely this only happens when the program is running and not when debugging line by line. I saw in other posts that this happens when the element is destroyed (which it does do) but the **var images** shouldn't be referring to the same elements since it's new each loop and that doesn't explain why it doesn't happen when I do it line by line.

Full code For context.

```
public static List<String> Process()
        {
            List<String> PhotoUrls = new List<String>();           
            var currenth = 0;
            var currenthn = 0;

            do
            {


                try
                {
                    //WaitForReady(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                    var currenthh = driver.ExecuteScript("return document.body.scrollHeight;");
                    currenth = Convert.ToInt32(currenthh);

                    driver.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0," + currenth +");");

                    var images = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".v1Nh3 a"));                                       

                    for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string url = images[i].GetAttribute("href");
                        string rp1 = url.Replace("https://wwwcom/p/", "");
                        string rp2 = rp1.Replace("/", "");

                        PhotoUrls.Add(rp2);
                    }
                    WaitTime(3000, 1000);


                    var currenthhn = driver.ExecuteScript("return document.body.scrollHeight;");
                    currenthn = Convert.ToInt32(currenthhn);

                   // currenth = (int)driver.ExecuteScript("return document.body.scrollHeight;");
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

            } while (currenth != currenthn);

            
            return PhotoUrls;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is likely changing after you scroll:

```
driver.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0," + currenth +");");
```

After executing the line above, the browser scrolls down. JavaScript may be showing or hiding elements as you scroll — in the very least it is changing the elements on the page as you scroll.

You might just need to get all of the images again on each iteration of the loop:

```
Func<ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>> getImages = () => driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".v1Nh3 a"));

for (int i = 0; i < getImages().Count; i++)
{
    string url = getImages().ElementAt(i).GetAttribute("href");
    string rp1 = url.Replace("https://wwwcom/p/", "");
    string rp2 = rp1.Replace("/", "");

    PhotoUrls.Add(rp2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! however, this code gives mea syntax error that I 
cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of <IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>>
on
string url = getImages()[i].GetAttribute("href")

Comment: @TimStevens: I'll try to fix it tomorrow.

Comment: @TimStevens: Updated. Hopefully that fixes the syntax error.

Comment: Yes that seems to have worked thanks! @greg